# Python threads and linux ioctl wait

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

I have the following toy example for Python threading module

```
from __future__ import print_function
import threading
import time
import signal
import sys
import os
import time

class ThreadShutdown(Exception):
    # Custom exception to allow clean thread exit
    pass

def thread_shutdown(signum, frame):
    print(" o Signal {} caught and raising ThreadShutdown exception".format(signum))
    raise ThreadShutdown

def main():

    """
    Register the signal handlers needed to stop 
    cleanly the child accessing thread
    """
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, thread_shutdown)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, thread_shutdown)

    test_run_seconds = 120

    try:
        thread = ChildThread()
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        while test_run_seconds > 0:
            test_run_seconds -= 1
            print(" o [{}] remaining time is {} seconds".format(time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) ), test_run_seconds))
            time.sleep(1)

    except ThreadShutdown:
        thread.shutdown_flag.set()
        thread.join()
        print(" o ThreadShutdown procedure complete")
        return

    proc.terminate()
    thread.shutdown_flag.set()
    thread.join()
    print(" o Test terminated")

class ChildThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.shutdown_flag = threading.Event()

    def run(self):

        while not self.shutdown_flag.is_set(): 
            print(" o [{}] is the current time in child, sleep for 10s".format(time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()))))
            time.sleep(10)

        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

which behaves as expected (the main thread counts every second while the spawned thread prints only every 10 seconds.

I was trying to understand the behaviour of the same code snippet in presence of blocking waits in kernel mode in the spawned thread. For example, assume that the spawned thread now goes into a killable wait in an ioctl with a timeout of 10s, I would still expect to have the main thread counting every second. For some reason, it instead counts every 10s, as if it was blocked as well in the wait of the spawned thread. What is the reason?

Comment: `I would still expect to have the main thread counting every second. For some reason, it instead counts` - Please show the code where that happens. How exactly did you test it?

Comment: I'm using a subprocess.Popen() call to a process which does a custom made ioctl that performs a killable wait with a 10 seconds timeout (which expires) instead of doing the `time.sleep(10)` in the code above.

Comment: Code speaks 1000 words. Please, rather then explaining what the code does, please _show_ the code itself. Where do you call popen? How do you call it? What process do you call? What ioctl does it do? Please create an [MCVE]. Please specify all the steps needed to reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: it's several hundreds of lines of code here, I can't show the whole thing. the popen replaces the line of the code above which does time.sleep(10)